# undefined error inside the get function on ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Good day, I was having this weird problem on my ajax code please take a look:

```
$(".productDropdown").bind("change", productDropdown);
function productDropdown(){

    $.get('/api/productDropdown', 
    { option: $(this).val() }, 
    function(data) {    

    var parent = $(this).parents('tr'); 
    var qty = $(parent).find('input.qty').val();
    var price = $(parent).find('input.price').val();
    var description = $(parent).find('textarea.description').val();

    console.log(price+":"+qty+":"+description);

    });

}
```

log result is :

```
undefined:undefined:undefined
```

but when i declare the variables outside the get function I can get the correct value. But still i cant assign them on text box. Because when i tried putting:

```
description.val(data.description);
```

below the variables i get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'val' of undefined
```

(this is an external js file)

(UPDATED)

heres my HTML file:

```
<table id="tblContacts" class="table-responsive table table-striped table-bordered tablesorter table-hover col-lg-12">            
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-lg-3">Product Name</th>
                <th class="col-lg-4">Description</th>
                <th class="col-lg-1">Quantity</th>
                <th class="col-lg-1">Price</th>
                <th class="col-lg-3">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var my_var = {"":"Please select","1":"Paracetamol","2":"Biogesic","3":"Bioflu","4":"Medicol"};
        </script>

     <select class="form-control productDropdown" placeholder="Company Name" id="productId" required="required" name="product[0][name]">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Please select</option>
    <option value="1">Paracetamol</option>
    <option value="2">Biogesic</option>
    <option value="3">Bioflu</option>
    <option value="4">Medicol</option>
</select>                        
</td>
                <td><textarea name='product[0][description]' class="form-control description" rows="1" required></textarea>
                    </td>
                <td><input type='number' min="1" max="9999"   name='product[0][quantity]' class="form-control qty" required value="52"></td>
                <td><input type='number' min="0.5" max="9999"   name='product[0][price]' class="form-control price" required/></td>
                <td>
                <a href="#" class="btnRemoveRow btn btn-danger">Remove</a>

                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

any idea please...Your help would really be appreciated, Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You can't use `$(this)` inside your success function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` inside your success function is not what you expect it to be. You need to define a variable before your `$.get` and use that inside the success function:

```
$(".productDropdown").bind("change", productDropdown);

function productDropdown() { 
    var target = $(this);
    $.get('/api/productDropdown', {
        option: $(this).val()
    }, function (data) {

        var parent = target.parents('tr');
        var qty = $(parent).find('input.qty').val();
        var price = $(parent).find('input.price').val();
        var description = $(parent).find('textarea.description').val();

        console.log(price + ":" + qty + ":" + description);

    });
}
```

Comment: there is still one error why is it i cant use ` price.val(data.price);` im getting an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'val' of undefined thanks..

Comment: How are you doing that? Maybe you can add that to your question.

Comment: oohhh.. it was just an error on my part because i declared price = $this.find(input.price).val(); and then I assign in later to price.val(data.price); it means that I actually assigned two .val on the price variable... im sorry for that it was my mistake.. anyways thank for very much for your willingness to help! :) GOOD DAY!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".productDropdown").bind("change", productDropdown);
function productDropdown(){

    var $this = $(this);

    $.get('/api/productDropdown', 
    { option: $this.val() }, 
    function(data) {    

    var parent = $this.parents('tr'); 
    var qty = $(parent).find('input.qty').val();
    var price = $(parent).find('input.price').val();
    var description = $(parent).find('textarea.description').val();

    console.log(price+":"+qty+":"+description);

    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you @kehrk for that information and for giving a quick fix! I didnt know about that.. Really appreciated it!

Comment: @user2997398 Not a problem. I'm sure I've run into this same issue in the past.

Comment: there is still one error why is it i cant use ` price.val(data.price);` im getting an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'val' of undefined

Comment: I don't think I can figure that out without seeing the HTML of the `.productDropdown` element and the HTML of its parents.